# extra vertical space added while not needed

Tags: css

I am having trouble to figure out why I have an extra vertical space between 2 divs

Here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/karimmtlc/bqt1r4y2/

and here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="voyage_map"  style="width: 100%; height: 400px; padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:blue;">
        </div>
        <div id="voyage_map_container" style="z-index:1000000000000; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);position:relative;top:-120px; min-height:120px; color:white;padding-top:0px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:5px;"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8" style="padding-top:2px;"><h3 style="padding-top:0px;"><strong>Title here</strong></h3><div id="trun3">Start making your clients happy! shhhe ejhjdajfb fdhdf chcdb sgsghgs shgfhdg dhhdshdhfgd dcbdhhsdb Start making your clients happy! shhhe ejhjdajfb fdhdf chcdb sgsghgs shgfhdg dhhdshdhfgd dcbdhhsdb Start making your clients happy! shhhe ejhjdajfb fdhdf chcdb sgsghgs shgfhdg dhhdshdhfgd dcbdhhsdb Start making your clients happy! shhhe ejhjdajfb fdhdf chcdb sgsghgs shgfhdg dhhdshdhfgd dcbdhhsdb Start making your clients happy! shhhe ejhjdajfb fdhdf chcdb sgsghgs shgfhdg dhhdshdhfgd dcbdhhsdb sgsghgs shgfhdg dhhdshdhfgd dcbdhhsdb Start making your clients happy! shhhe ejhj shs sbsbhsbds sbsdbsbd Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy! Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!Start making your clients happy!</div></div><div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-right" style="padding-top:5px;"><h3 style="padding-top:2px;"><strong>MAY 26TH-29TH 2015</strong></h3></div></div></div>
        <div style="background-color: green;min-height=100;">ssdsdsdsdsd</div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The extra vertical space that i want to get rid of is between the gray background and the green background.

Thanks

Comment: Because div `#voyage_map_container` has `top:-120px`

Comment: And `z-index:1000000000000;` is too small, you should choose larger value.

Comment: @c-smile: :-) there is a reason for that i am using a plugin that adds a very high z-index.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bqt1r4y2/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div `#voyage_map_container` is relative positioned and has `top:-120px;`.

Edit the following:

```
<div id="voyage_map_container" style="z-index:1000000000000; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);position:relative;top:-120px; min-height:120px; color:white;padding-top:0px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:5px;">
```

To:

```
<div id="voyage_map_container" style="z-index:1000000000000; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);position:relative; min-height:120px; color:white;padding-top:0px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:5px;">
```

If by design you need to have that element positioned like you have now, you can also add `margin-bottom: -120px;` to the same element in order to "pull" the elements bellow.

Comment: I need the gray div to be positioned that way (120px on top of the blue div). I guess the question now is how to do that and have those 120px freed after it so the next element would be just after with no extra vertical space.